# Mocking apache.commons.io.IOUtils class

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, apache-commons-io

I need to mock toByteArray() of apache.commons.io.IOUtils class.
I've a code snippet like ths:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(IOUtils.class);
PowerMockito.when(IOUtils.toByteArray(any(InputStream.class))).thenReturn(mockByteArray);
```

But I'm getting NullPointerException from org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge() function.

Comment: Have you added `@PrepareForTest(IOUtils.class);` ?

Comment: Alternatively, create an interface that offers IO operations and call `IOUtils` in your concrete implementation. Mock the interface for your tests (e.g. with regular Mockito). This has the added advantage of decoupling your IO routines from a specific implementation (i.e. Apache Commons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the method is not mocked and the real method is called instead.

PowerMock uses special test runner that can mock static methods.

Put `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and  `@PrepareForTest(IOUtils.class)` annotations on your test class.

See example at [docs](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage)

Comment: Yep, I missed adding `@PrepareForTest(IOUtils.class)`. My bad. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: My test already has `@RunWith ( MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. How do I do it with this.?

Comment: Mockito cannot [mock static methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#can-i-mock-static-methods). Use PowerMock instead.